# NSData conversion of rupee symbol is returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, special-characters, nsdata

Below conversion of "₹" symbol is returning nil. Is rupee symbol accepted in mac roman?

```
let sourceData = (("₹test") as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding) as NSData
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The [Macintosh Roman](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Roman) encoding *cannot* represent the "₹" character. You have to
choose a different encoding for your data, for example `NSUTF8StringEncoding` (which can represent *all* valid Unicode characters).

Note that you don't need the `NSString` conversion:

```
let sourceData = "₹test".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```